# How background-property works in CSS Sprites?

Tags: html, css

I'm currently reviewing [Jhon Duckett's HTML&CSS book](http://htmlandcssbook.com/) more precisely [CSS Image Rollover and Sprites](http://htmlandcssbook.com/code-samples/chapter-16/image-rollovers-and-sprites.html) however I cannot yet wrap myself about this code and how's enterly being displayed.

I understand the idea behind using three images for different states using pseudo classes like :hover and :active however my two main questions are:

- How is the background-position property actively working to create this sort of "animation"?
- How when you :hover the links, the color of the anchor element turns green?

Excuse me in advance if the questions are too vague or subjective, I just wanted to receive a proper explanation to understand the topic.

Ps: For some reason I cannot make the snippet to run properly in this post, however the code has been attached. I hope it helps.

Thank you very much in advance!

[Image of the rendering of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gy1h3.png)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Image Rollovers and Sprites</title>
  <style type="text/css">
    a.button {
      height: 36px;
      background-image: url("images/button-sprite.jpg");
      text-indent: -9999px;
      display: inline-block;
    }
    
    a#add-to-basket {
      width: 174px;
      background-position: 0px 0px;
    }
    
    a#framing-options {
      width: 210px;
      background-position: -175px 0px;
    }
    
    a#add-to-basket:hover {
      background-position: 0px -40px;
    }
    
    a#framing-options:hover {
      background-position: -175px -40px;
    }
    
    a#add-to-basket:active {
      background-position: 0px -80px;
    }
    
    a#framing-options:active {
      background-position: -175px -80px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <a class="button" id="add-to-basket">Add to basket</a>
  <a class="button" id="framing-options">Framing options</a>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: simply read about background in general and more particular background-position. You have a big image and you are sliding it to show a portion of it

Comment: Here's the MDN reading: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-position
But as a small explanation, the button is acting like a window into the larger image of sprites. You can only see a certain section of the image through the window, and the image is placed so that it lines up with a sprite

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

background-position can take keywords like "center", "top", "left" or more specific values in px, percentages, etc. 
In this case, the button has been given exact height and width dimensions. This allows you to position the background image as you see fit inside the specified dimensions. 
The sprite in this example has the two buttons in both colors. If you want to see how the sprite is moving, you could add `transition: all 3s ease`. Maybe that will help you see how background-position is being used.

Comment: Thanks Jeff, your answer is much appreciated and it helped me to see what was happening.